# Find documents that has no reference from another collection on large DB

Tags: mongodb, sitecore, sitecore8

I am using MongoDB 3.2.5. There are 2 collections, both contain about 2 millions documents

```
Devices
{
    _id: xx
}

Interactions
{
    _id: yy
    StartDateTime: 2016-10-24 17:21:30.989Z
    DeviceId: xx
}
```

I want to find all devices that has no reference from interactions. I have tried the following code, it works with a small DB but fails on a large DB.

```
var matches = db.Interactions.find({}, { DeviceId: 1 });
var devicesIds = [];
matches.forEach(function(match) { devicesIds.push(match.DeviceId) });
var count = db.Devices.find({ "_id": { $nin : devicesIds } } ).count();
print(count);
```

It throws error message:

> [thread1] Error: BufBuilder attempted to grow() to 134217728 bytes, past the 64MB limit.

I also tried:

```
db.Devices.aggregate([
    {
      $lookup:
        {
          from: "Interactions",
          localField: "_id",
          foreignField: "DeviceId",
          as: "matched_docs"
        }
   },
   {
      $match: { "matched_docs": { $eq: [] } }
   },
   {
      $out: "TempDevicesNoInteraction"
   }
]);
```

The query run 3 hours but still not finish. I have to cancel it. Same for query below:

```
var count = 0;

db.Devices.find().forEach(function(myDoc) {
    var cursor = db.Interactions.find({DeviceId: myDoc._id});
    if(!cursor.hasNext()) {
        count = count + 1;
    }
});

print(count);
```

I am new to MongoDB, please guide me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you have a Index set on the "DeviceId" field in Interactions collection?
If not the Aggregation with the $lookup operator does a collectionscan (on 2million documents) for each of your 2million documents....

So please make sure there is an **index** on "DeviceId".

Do you plan on running this query often? When the answer is yes, you could store the results of you aggregation in a new collection using the [$out operator](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/reference/operator/aggregation/out/). This way the initial fill can takes some time but each query on that data performs well. But it's an consideration you have to make.

Comment: I don't have index on "DeviceId" field in Interactions collection. After I add index, aggregate command run successfully.